# Do I need to keep a reference to preloaded images or can they be garbage collected?

Tags: javascript

Every example of image preloaders that I find in books or online contains some form of a `cache` array of all the preloaded images.

I've created a [DEMO page](http://jsfiddle.net/7hapx/) that if you open the console, you can clearly see it preloads images even if they get garbage collected.

Is there any reason why all the other preloaders keep a reference to the preloaded images, or is it unnecessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it's not useful to keep a cache of loaded images since the browser already do that automatically. But if those libraries you mentioned do it, they might have a reason. Maybe for animation purposes since loading the image from JavaScript memory might be faster than loading it from the browser cache.